# unable to run inline query - select DATABASEPROPERTYEX('master', 'Collation') SQLCollation in ef core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am currently migrating to Entity Framework to EF Core.

But I am not able to migrate below code to EF core.

```
    var collation = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<string>(string.Format("SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('{0}', 'Collation') SQLCollation", InitialCatalog)).Single();
```

is there anyway to do it EF core without using ADO.NET?

Comment: EF Core 7 supports this directly.